# Fetch value of Dynamic textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating a textbox at runtime using javascript and passing its value to my servlet page using a href(which is also created at run time along with the textbox) but somehow the value is being passed as "Null". I am not understanding it why..Can anyone help me on this ??

Here is my javascript code :

```
//here I am creating textbox
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" id =\"in_nm\" SIZE=\"18\"  STYLE=\"height:24;border: 1 solid;margin:0;\">";
td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g, count);

//Here I am fetching its value
var nm=document.getElementById("in_nm");//this value is being passed null

//Here I am passing it through a href tag 
var strHtml3 = "<a id=\"link\" href=\"UserHandler?action=insert&&name="+nm+"\">Add Row</a>";
td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);
var dt=document.getElementById('in_dt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You never put your HTML string into the document, so you can't fetch it from the document.

Comment: How can I solve this..sorry but I am quite a bit new to Javascript

Comment: Put it in an element or in the document.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it as i already told you i am new to javascript and i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The DOM you have created never been placed in the document so you can't catch it.
In addition, if you immidietly catch the element it will be empty all the time.

You can append the input field to the body as hidden and then to fetch it.

```
strHtml1.style.display = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(strHtml1);
// At this point the dom is in the HTML and it is not visible and now you can use it.
```

Add it before your fetching the value.

Comment: can you tell me how to place my DOM to the document

Comment: I've added an example how to add the new DOM to the document. After you make the above code you can get the value from the input.

Comment: If I add the above statements in my code, it stops creating new textboxes

Comment: At the end you can set the strHtml1 display style to "block"

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing similar problem as mine, I am posting the solution for their reference

The problem was solved by fetching the value onchange and passing request through ajax as :

```
$(".edit_trr").click(function() //edit_trr is my class of the dynamic row added
            {

            }).change(function()
            {
                var nam=$("#in_name").val(); //in_name is my id of the textfield
                var datastr='name='+nam;
                if(nam.length >0) //checks if there is value in textfield
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "add.jsp", //link of my jsp page where data is added in database
                        data: datastr,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            alert('Inserted');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Enter Something');
                }
            });
```

On JSP page request send can simply be fetched as :

```
 request.getParameter("name");
```